# Deserializing a local xml file using Rest Sharp

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, restsharp

I have no problem deserializing an xml into my class while using the following code.  I was wondering if it was possible to use the same code on a local file, as our source files are saved locally for archival purposes and are occasionally reprocessed.

This works for remote xml but not for local xml:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
var client = new RestClient();

//doesnt work
client.BaseUrl = directory;
request.Resource = file;

//works
client.BaseUrl = baseURL;
request.Resource = url2;


IRestResponse<T> response = client.Execute<T>(request);
return response.Data;
```

Is there a way to use RestSharp from a local file?  I was going to try to use the same function regardless of whether the xml is local or remote and just pass it the location of the xml to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with standard functionality. For example "file://" URLs do not work with RestSharp.

I would recommend using RestSharp do get the returned data from a Uri and having another function to deserialize this data into an object.

You can use the same funcion then to deserialize from file data.

RestSharp is a library to do REST calls, not to deserialize from arbitrary sources. Even if there is a possibility to make RestSharp believe it is talking to a website instead of a file, it would be a hack.

If you need it you could still use the `XmlDeserializer` from RestSharp. It expects a `IRestResponse` object, but it only uses the `Content` property from it, so it should be easy to create. It still feels like a hack though and there are more than enough other `XmlSerializers` out there that will do a great job

Comment: In your last sentence, I believe that you meant, "talking to a file instead of a website."  Thank you for the response.  I'd upvote, but I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: No, I was saying that you could try to make RestSharp believe it is talking to a website, but actually it is talking to a file. Anyway, if you like the answer you should click the accept answer button. This does not require reputation.

Comment: Ah, thank you, understood.  Yeah, it felt a little too hacky when I thought of and tried it, I just didn't know.  More than anything I was looking to bounce the idea off of someone else.  I'll just use an xmldeserializer.

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact possible using built in `JsonDeserializer` class as below. I have used this method to stub API response for testing.

```
// Read the file

string fileContents = string.Empty;

using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Path_to_File.txt"))
{
    fileContents = rd.ReadToEnd();
}

// Deserialize
RestResponse<T> restResponse = new RestResponse<T>();

restResponse.Content = fileContents;

RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();

T deserializedObject = deserializer.Deserialize<T>(restResponse);
```